# how to test if an open graph image has been set

Tags: open-graph

Our content mostly has Open Graph information set. I think this is done by Yoast SEO. Do you think this is correct?

There are quite a few (~1200) URLs that have no Open Graph image set.

I am thinking I can write a `functions.php` action to check to see if the Open Graph image has been set, and if not, supply a fallback OG image.

How would I check to see if an OG image has not been set?

Help appreciated.

Comment: "I think this is done by Yoast SEO" - try searching in and/or asking on the plugin support forums. I would also check the plugin's documentations and codebase for relevant information..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoast SEO has a provision for a default social image through

`Yoast SEO > Social > Facebook > Default image`.